# Fetching time zones using different Application Servers produces Unexpected results

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

**I have two applications with different time zones.**

**Application 1:**  -Duser.timezone=Australia/Darwin

**Application 2:**  -Duser.timeZone=Asia/Kolkata

Application 1 inserts TimeStamp based on Zone1 and Application2 inserts TimeStamp based on Zone2.

While fetching data from Application1, Zone conversion is not done.
Instead it displays the same result.

**Values inserted to DB:**

2019-02-19 15:39:40 - Application1

2019-02-19 11:40:09 - Application2

**Output when fetched from Application 1/ Application2**

Time Stamp  from DB: 2019-02-19 15:39:40.0

Time Stamp  from DB: 2019-02-19 11:40:09.0

For Example , if data is read from Application 1, time Stamp should be displayed according to Austria/Darwin.

**How to achieve this?**

Here is the code snippet.

```
String selectSQL = "select createdtime from TZ_TEST6";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(selectSQL );



while (rs.next())
    {
         Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(1);
         System.out.println("Time Stamp  from DB: " +timestamp);
    }
```

Comment: “MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval.” ([Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)) So this is the datatype you should use. Then store and retrieve `OffsetDateTime` to and from the database (not the poorly designed and long outdated `Timestamp`).

Comment: While retrieving data from Application2(Australia/Darwin), all the time stamps persisted in the DB has to be converted to the current time zone((Australia/Darwin). This is my understanding. But, my output shows otherwise.

Comment: There are a number of seemingly similar questions, for example [MySQL Time zone confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071287/mysql-time-zone-confusion). Search for more.

Comment: Are you saving timezone info along with timestamp in the DB?