# Hibernate saves/retrieves date minus day if application uses another timezone than MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, timezone

I have an application started on tomcat on MACHINE_A with timezone GMT+3.

I use remote MySQL server started on MACHINE_B with timezone UTC.

We use spring-data-jpa for persistence.

As an example of the problem, I will show the repository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyInstance, Long> {
    Optional<MyInstance> findByDate(LocalDate localDate);
}
```

If I pass localDate for `2018-09-06`, I get entities where the date is `2018-09-05`(previous day)

In the logs I see:

```
2018-09-06 18:17:27.783 TRACE 13676 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2018-09-06]
```

I googled that question a lot and found several articles with the same content(for example https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/)

So, I have the following `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MYDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: root
    password: *****
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
        format_sql: true
        type: trace
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
```

But it doesn't help.

We use the following connector:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I resolve my problem?

### P.S.

I tried to run both applications with the same time zone. In this case, everything works as expected.

### P.S.2

I tried to use MySQL driver 6.0.6 version but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried to use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead of LocalDate in `MyRepository`?

Comment: @Boris, spring data jpa doesn't work with it. I see error: Parameter value [2018-10-02T00:00Z] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2018-10-02T00:00Z] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]

Comment: But according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43898668/3301492) it should be possible. Spring Data JPA 1.11 [supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-11-0) Hibernate 5.2 which [supports](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-datetime-java8) Java 8 Date/Time Values.

Comment: @Boris, I use newer version. My experiment shows that it is wrong.

Comment: When you try with `ZonedDateTime`, why do we see the exception complaining about `LocalDate`? Have you left the type of date in `MyInstance` as `LocalDate`?

Comment: @Boris, good point. I will able to check on monday

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`

Comment: As I stated in my answer, I think the `JVM` time zone has to be set to UTC and it is not only a `Hibernate` thing.

Comment: @Rick James, system_time_zone UTC
time_zone SYSTEM

Comment: @gstackoverflow can you try by passing local date with UTC zone id like for current LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")); for your date please just use zone id with it then pass to repository method.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using `LocalDate` in Java, you should use a `DATE` column in MySQL. This way the problem will be solved.

If you use `LocalDateTime`, try setting the property like this in Spring Boot:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

To see it working in action, you can find a test case in my [High-Performance Java Persistence GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/time/UTCTimeZoneMySQLTimestampTest.java) which demonstrates how this setting works with MySQL.

Comment: But looks like I have it in my yml file. Could you check if I set it correctly?

Comment: How can I check that hibernate got that property?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at [this line](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/b3c2c2fe47ef5cf35c5ae1bf64e89efddbc716dc/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/internal/SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java#L456) in `SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder`.

Comment: I see in dependencies hibernate-core:5.2.17

Comment: I found line: ** Object jdbcTimeZoneValue = configurationSettings.get(
     JDBC_TIME_ZONE
   ); ** and it evaluates as UTC in org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl

Comment: Then, you need to debug it to see why it does not work for you and compare to [this test](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/time/UTCTimeZoneMySQLTimestampTest.java) in my high-performance-java-persistence repository which works fine.

Comment: You at least use newer version of hibernate. and older version of mysql(you use 6, but I use 8)

Comment: Try to upgrade the Driver in my repository and see if the test breaks.

Comment: Moreover you verifies data and time. In my case I use localDate which doesn't have time

Comment: Then you should map it to a MySQL `DATE` column and the problem is solved.

Comment: In database I have DATE column.

Comment: any ideas? Do you understand that advise you provided was applied in my question and it doesn't work for me?

Comment: it is not working: Especially in this case"LocalDate in Java, you should use a DATE" and using  "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=CET" neither helps.

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issues while creating some integration tests for a `spring-boot` application using `hibernate`. The database I used here was `postgreSQL`.

As another answer correctly points out, you can set the `hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC` property like discribed. Nevermind this didn't solve my issues, so I had to set the `JVM` default time zone with the help of the following in my `spring-boot` applications main class:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   // It will set UTC timezone
    System.out.println("Spring boot application running in UTC timezone :"+new Date());   // It will print UTC timezone
}
```

This should also solve your problems. You can gather more informations [here](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-application-set-default-timezone/).

**Reason**

I guess your problem (retrieving date - 1 day) comes from your specific setup. If your application is running in UTC and requesting timestamps from a database in GMT+3 it resolves in a earlier date, because the applications context (`JVM` and `Hibernate` are responsible here) is 3 hours behind the database context in UTC. Simple example:

`2018-12-02 00:00:00` - 3hours = `2018-12-01 21:00:00`

As you are only looking to the dates: `2018-12-02` - 3hours = `2018-12-01`

Comment: your approach will work but we are not able to guarantee that all servers will work in UTC

Comment: @gstackoverflow this shouldn't be an issue here, because the described `init()` method sets the java TimeZone to UTC, no matter what TimeZone the server is in.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the MySQL Connector prior to version 8.0.22, see [Spring data query for localdate returns wrong entries - minus one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755249/spring-data-query-for-localdate-returns-wrong-entries-minus-one-day/64930704#64930704)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your both servers should be in same time zone and preferred one be in UTC time zone. And to show correct time to user in his timezone; you parse it in browser itself. And while retrieving data from DB; you use UTC time. This way you will not have issue while fetching data from DB

Comment: Actually, ideally the **time zone of your servers should be *irrelevant***. Your programming should specify explicitly the desired/expected time zones as as optional arguments to the date-time classes rather than relying implicitly on current default time zones.

Comment: I agree with the comment of Basil Bourque. In times of (globaly) distributed databases and microservice architectures you clearly have to understand the time zone topic of both, your application and the underlying database. Nevermind, the time zones should be abstracted and therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL...

`TIMESTAMP` internally stores UTC, but converts to/from the server's timezone based on two settings.  Check those settings via `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`  Properly configured, the reader may see a different time than the writer (based on tz settings).

`DATE` and `DATETIME` take whatever you give it.  There is no tz conversion between the string in the client and what is stored in the table.  Think of it a storing a picture of a clock.  The reader will see the *same* time string that the writer wrote.

Comment: system_time_zone UTC
time_zone SYSTEM

Answer (score 0):

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`

It's used when you are working TimeZoned Date, but from your logs it seems you are not passing TimeZone:

> binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2018-09-06]

Try to remote property:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following parsing to your HQL query, it will return a date without any time zone format or time of day. This is a quick workaround to your issue.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') from Entity
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done everything as instructed in the answers before, like

- Adding spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=America/Sao_Paulo
- Setting default timezone: `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"))`

but none of them worked until I add the parameter **serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo** in my JDBC url:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aurorabuzz-test?serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo
```

Now it's working just fine!