# Spring data query for localdate returns wrong entries - minus one day

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, timezone, spring-data

In my Entity i have a field of type **LocalDate** "day" in MySQL it is mapped to "date" type.

MySQL seems to run on UTC `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);` is returning `00:00:00`. My system is running CET (UTC+1)

If i query it via sql (console from IntelliJ configured with **empty Time zone**) the query

```
select * from table where day = '2020-10-18';
```

Returns entries with correct date.

The query specified with Spring data `findByDay` is also looking correct:

2020-11-09 16:16:32.911 DEBUG 5600 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        :    select {all fields} from table entity0_ where entity0_.tag=?
2020-11-09 16:16:32.924 TRACE 5600 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder          : binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2020-10-18]

But it is returning entries with **date = 2020-10-17**

Thus my test is always failing:

```
@Test
void getWithoutMeldebereiche() {
    LocalDate of = LocalDate.of(2020, 10, 18);
    List<Entity> without =
            repository.findByDay(of);
    assertThat(without, is(not(empty())));
    assertThat(without.get(0).getTag(), is(of) ); //fails due to wrong date
}
```

The data source is also configured without time zone (as it is configured in IntelliJ):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF8
```

How to make this query and test work independently of client (system time zone) server (kind of data base, time zone of server)  (i ' dont have control over them)? Why it is working if i query via IntelliJ - also no time zone set?

Are there better types than "LocalDate" mapped to "date" that can be used for this use case that are really dates and thus time-zone-less?

what i tried so far:
not working:

- spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=CET does not help
- spring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Duser.timezone=UTC is not working

working but makes me dependent of set up in target environment:

- adding &serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin on connection url **helps** but this i can't control in other environments. and this is only working for MySql.
- adding `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the MySQL Connector/J earlier than version 8.0.22. Updating to 8.0.22 will fix the issue.

From the [8.0.22 changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-22.html#connector-j-8-0-22-bug):

> LocalDate, LocalDateTime, and LocalTime values set through Connector/J
> were altered when there was a timezone difference between the server
> and the client. This fix corrects the issue by handling the LocalDate,
> LocalTime, and LocalDateTime with no time zone conversion and no
> intermediate conversions to other date-time classes.

The underlying bug:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444

Comment: you saved my day - this indeed helped. it works now without the setup stuff - as it should.

Comment: i am using 8.0.25 and im having the same issue

Comment: after i changed the pom.xml auto defined version by spring to explicit mysql version 8.0.26 ,it  started yielding correct results, wich is strange,because the auto managed version is the same. * edit : and it started to do the same -1 day after a clean-build-run...