# The server time zone value 'Ostereuropeische Zeit' is unrecognized

Tags: mysql, datetime, jdbc, timezone

I have this error:

"The server time zone value 'Osteuropeische Zeit' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specific time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support."

OS used is Win 10, but it was installed as a German version. I believe that's where the problem comes from. I've set the display language to English, but it didn't help.

Thank you!

Comment: I would try simply hour notation: `+01:00` indicating offset from UTC. Additionally list of time zones: `SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses [zoneinfo](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) [names -- based on political subdivisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) -- to name timezones.  These look like `'Europe/Helsinki'` or `'Europe/Athens'` rather than generic names. Why? zoneinfo attempts to handle both daylight and standard time, and those rules depend on said political subdivisions.

All this zoneinfo stuff is built into UNIX-derived operating systems, so MySQL servers running on Linux transparently use those timezones.  Zoneinfo is not built into Windows, so if your MySQL *server* runs there, you must set up the server timezone lookup tables yourself, [with this procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation).

You can set the MySQL default server timezone in a number of ways. Look up how to do these. These are a few of the ways.

1. In [my.cnf, MySQL's configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562456/mysql-setting-time-zone-in-my-cnf-options-file).
2. On your JDBC connection string add a parameter like `&serverTimezone=Europe/Helsinki`
3. Once you have established your MySQL connection give the SQL command `SET time_zone='Europe/Helsinki'` (or whatever you require).

You can also set this up in your Java program. Look up how to do that.

MySQL's internal `TIMESTAMP` data type, and the values of functions like `NOW()`, are inherently in UTC.  But MySQL translates them from UTC to your chosen timezone on display, and translates them to UTC upon storing.

So, in many applications (WordPress for example) the timezone setting is a user preference.