# Members site last login date time stamp

Tags: php

I run a website for a local organisation where members log in using their own logins. I have quite basic knowledge, so this may be a simple fix..

I have the following code as part of the php run when they successfully log in which saves their log in date & time to the MySQL database.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE accounts SET lastlogin = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?');
```

The problem is that the date and time stored is 2 hours behind our local time (New Zealand). I've searched around the net for this answer but get lost in everything that's out there! What am I missing in this code to save the date & time as local?

Thanks!

Comment: Update DB to use same timezone as application, or update code base to convert from GMT to local timezone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: setting time\_zone in my.cnf options file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562456/mysql-setting-time-zone-in-my-cnf-options-file)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because the database's time zone differs from your local time zone.

Make sure you first set default time zone in PHP like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');
```

This is how I fixed it.

```
$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET lastlogin = '{$current_time}' WHERE id = ?");
```

Comment: `$current_time` should be bound. As is SQL wouldn't run. `H:is` also is missing a colon.

Comment: Thanks @ruleboy21, this is what im looking for. I've checked the default timezone and it is indeed set as Pacific/Auckland. When I apply the code you suggested, unfortunately it just cleared the date & time back to all zeros when I logged in..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check the `$current_time`.

Comment: Excellent, that's got it. Cheers!